# ¿Por qué solo imprime un nodo?

Tags: c++, lista, punteros, revisión-de-código

Tengo que hacer una lista doblemente ligada, agregar y mostrar y pero cuando hace la función de mostrar solamente muestra el primer elemento de la lista.

```
struct dato {
    int info;
    dato* sig;
    dato* ant;
}*origen, * ultimo, * aux, * aux2;


void nuevo() {
    if (origen == NULL) {
        system("cls");
        origen = new dato;
        origen->ant = NULL;
        origen->sig = NULL;
        cout << "Ingresa el dato: ";
        cin >> origen->info;
        aux  = origen;
        ultimo = origen;

    }
    else {
        aux = origen;
        while (aux != NULL) {
            aux = aux->sig;

        }
        aux = new dato;
        aux->sig = NULL;
        aux->ant = ultimo;
        
        system("cls");
        cout << "Ingresa el dato: ";
        cin >> aux->info;
        ultimo = aux;
        
    }
}

void mostrar() {
    aux = origen;
    int a = 1;
    while ( aux!=NULL) {
        cout << "Dato " << a << " es: " << aux->info<<"\n";
        aux = aux->sig;
        a++;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema está al insertar:

```
aux = new dato;
aux->sig = NULL;
aux->ant = ultimo;
...
ultimo = aux;
```

Asignas correctamente los datos al nuevo elemento que has creado ... Pero en ningún momento enlazas **el anterior con el recién creado**:

```
aux = new dato;
aux->sig = NULL;
aux->ant = ultimo;
ultimo->sig = aux; // <-- // Añadir esto
...
```